# merge jquery css range-bar with django templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I have two piece of code one is for django and other is for range slidebar. I want to put range bar which is on 2nd html into 1st html.

```
<html>
    <head>
        {% include display_static.html %}
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var map, marker, topmostID = {}, currentObject, geocoder;
            function initialize() {
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    zoom: 5,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(19.0861, 72.8530),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                });
                geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            }
        </script>

        <style>
            body {font-family: sans-serif}
            #map {width: 1200px; height: 600px}
        </style>

    </head>

    <body onload='initialize()'>
        <form  method=post action=" ">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type=submit value='Login'>
        </form>
        <div id=map></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

another piece is which is for range slide bar , some of the static files not written:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <script src="static/js/ion.rangeSlider.js"></script>
        <script>

            $(document).ready(function() {

                $("#range_45").ionRangeSlider({
                    type: "single",
                    grid: true,
                    values: [
                        "TEN - WROST", "nine", "eight",
                        "seven", "six", "five",
                        "four", "three", "two", "ONE - BEST"
                    ]
                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- Page contents -->
        <div style="position: relative; padding: 200px;">

            <div>
                <input type="text" id="range_45" value="" name="range" />
                <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit" />
            </div>

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Wtower i want a range slider bar (2nd code)along with the google map(1st code) how i can merge them. I don't know how to use jquery with django templates

Comment: You have to demonstrate some effort. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask